# mail function goes to junk mail when including html content

Tags: php, html, gmail

in my script I was using `mail()` function with html content as shown below:

`$message = "
    <html>
       <head>
           <title>Page Title</title>
       </head>
       <body style='direction: rtl;'>
           <p>Hi $name,</p>
           <p>some text: $sdesc</p>
           <p>Some text.</p>
           <p>some text:</p>
           <table>
              <tr>
                <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>number</th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>description</th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>price</th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>qty</th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>total</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$randnum</td>
                <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sdesc</td>
                <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$price</td>
                <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$qty</td>
                <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$total</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
         </body>
      </html>"`

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <example@mydomain.net>' . "\r\n";
$to = "myemail@example.com";
$subject = "My Subject";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

and my message was going directly to the junk mail.

But when I removed the html code and the headers, it is going now to the inbox.

```
$to = $breed;
        $subject = "My Subject";
        $message = "
            Hi $name,\r\n
            Some text: $sdesc\r\n
            Some text.\r\n
            Details:\r\n
            number: $randnum \r\n
            description: $sdesc \r\n
            price: $price \r\n
            qty: $qty \r\n
            total: $total \r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:example@example.net' . "\r\n";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

but I need to send an html message and prevent it from going to the junk mail.

any ideas?

I tried to write a code following the instructions here http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and it worked fine with gmail.

but still the same problem with hotmail.

Comment: You can't prevent it from going to junk. The mail server scans the email for signs of spam and gives it a "spam rating". The rating is basically how likely this is spam. If you want to prevent it from going to junk then run your emails through a spam rating checker. https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: May be this can be over come by using 3rd part API like Mailgun or postmark.

Comment: i tried https://www.mail-tester.com/ with my code without html but it is telling me "Your email will never see the light of an inbox" while it is goin to the inbox

Comment: It's easier to trouble shoot if you provide the report from mail-tester as well as the email headers. It could be because your IP was blacklisted, domain was blacklisted. It differs also on gmail or hotmail. Recommended is instead of using only text/html, you use "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" and provide text version as well.

Comment: What domain are you sending from and to? If you read the headers of the junk mail, you can see why it was categorised as spam. Again, you can post this here but be sure to remove email address.

Comment: See one of my other answers for a further checks on your domain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631734/php-mail-use-from-of-multiple-mail-client-yahoo-google-hotmail-rediff-p/40632170#40632170

Comment: in the junk mail it says: " It contains content that's typically used in spam messages" and thats why it is classified in the junk mail. but what kind of content in my code that is typically used in spam messages?!

Answer (score 0):

Try change the `$headers .= 'From:example@example.net' . "\r\n";`
To normal mail

Comment: actually I am using a normal email which belongs to my domain. but this one I wrote just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possible issues with the HTML content you're sending.

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
```

The content of an HTML email is treated as a document fragment, not as an entire document. You don't need to include `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` elements, and leaving them out may improve the deliverability of your message.

```
<body style='direction: rtl;'>
```

Do not use `direction: rtl` in HTML email. It has frequently been used to obfuscate the content of HTML messages.

If you are sending messages in an RTL language (such as Hebrew or Arabic), you will need to use workarounds. For instance, if you want the table headers to appear in right-to-left order (e.g, from number on the right to total on the left), include the columns in the reverse left-to-right order.